# two column and header css layout problem

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my first website and i'm having some trouble with css.
i want a two column + header layout that fully occupies the whole website screen space

i want the following specification:

- header 20 % of height screen
- left column 20% width screen & 80
  height screen(the remaining free
  space)
- right column 80 width screen & 80
  height screen(the remaining free
  space)

I also would like to have the div's not overlap each other.
I don't know if this is possible if you use % to specify the width and height, but i hope so :). I hope someone will help me. i will appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is your first website, I don't recommend doing things this way. You should assume that you'll get visitors on very different screen sizes where this fixed 100% height layout is going to be a problem. I'm telling you this from 12+ years experience building HTML sites. If you have a really good reason, go ahead though, just a friendly warning.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a dynamic height is very usual for a header, but if this is really what you want, then this should work:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
   <div id="left">
   </div>
   <div id="right">
   </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
html, body {
   height:100%; /* important for some browsers */
} 
#header {
   height:20%;
   width:100%;
} 
#content {
   height:80%;
   width:100%;
   float:left;
}
#left {
   width:20%;
   float:left;
}
#right {
   width:80%;
   float:left;
}
```